# Background task in Scala

Tags: multithreading, scala

I have a cache I want to periodically check and prune. In Java, I'd do the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  void run() {
    while (true) { 
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      // clear the cache's old entries
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Sure, I'd have some issues with thread-safe types to use as the cache, but putting that aside, my question is simple. What's the Scala way of running a recurring background task -- something you don't want running in the application's main thread?

I've used actors a bit and I guess my problem in this scenario is that I don't have anything to generate a message that it's time to clear the cache. Or rather, the only way I can imagine to generate those messages is to create a thread to do it...

**EDIT: I need people to vote on answers -- they all look good to me**

Comment: Thread spawning greatly depends on your system. It maybe to costly for you to have a thread for each such case. Take a look at ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, you can used it from Scala with some helpers defined in scala.concurrent package

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, but I would do something simple like the following.

```
import scala.concurrent.ops._

spawn {
  while (true) { 
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // clear the cache's old entries
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: .. and make sure you handle exceptions

Comment: I'm gonna go with this one, because I want a new thread in this case.

Comment: `scala.concurrent.ops` object is now deprecated (Since version 2.10.0).

Comment: @Naetmul, and what should be used instead?

Comment: @Kai can you please provide some links with examples?

Answer (score 11):

You could use [Akka Scheduler](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.2/common/scheduler.html), which allows you to send a reccuring message to an (akka) actor doing the job. From the doc, just use:

```
import akka.actor.Scheduler

//Sends messageToBeSent to receiverActor after initialDelayBeforeSending and then after each delayBetweenMessages
Scheduler.schedule(receiverActor, messageToBeSent, initialDelayBeforeSending, delayBetweenMessages, timeUnit)
```

Comment: I think that is code for early versions of Akka; to do the same thing with more recent versions, see http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/scheduler.html

Answer (score 7):

Futures is a simple way to do it without explicitly starting a new thread

```
import scala.actors.Futures._

// main thread code here

future {
   // second thread code here
}

// main thread code here
```

Comment: Futures are designed for _one time_ tasks not _recurring_ tasks.  The overhead is significant and unnecessary for a recurring task.

Comment: He clearly stated 'recurring'. There's nothing on recurring in your sample. Sorry, -1

Comment: @RexKerr: But the deprecation information regarding the accepted answer based on `spawn` gives the direction to replace `spawn` by a future. So what is the correct answer for Scala 2.10? @Jus12: To make this work one may have to `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. @akauppi: I would accept a `while (true) { ... }` in the future to somehow fulfill recurring...

Comment: @bluenote10 - I don't see any advantage of using a future over creating a new thread as in Java.  If you don't want to use Akka or deprecated methods, just do it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: @RexKerr: I was expecting that both approaches are technically equivalent and in this case one might argue that the syntactical simplification is a big advantage. I guess you favor the old-fashioned way for technical reasons (which I was not aware of)...

Comment: @bluenote10 - Futures generally run on thread pools that do not scale to the size of all available threads, and have additional overhead.  When choosing between a more expensive solution that uses a more limited resource, and less expensive one that uses a less limited resource, I tend to choose the less limited one.

Answer (score 7):

`spawn` is good but note that your sample code works in Scala too:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  override def run() {
    while (true) { 
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      // clear the cache's old entries
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Just clean it up with an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def funcToRunnable(f: => ()) = new Runnable() { override def run() { f() } }

new Thread{
  while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // blah
  }
}.start()
```

Comment: In my test (Scala 2.10.3) the implicit version is blocking, but the first is not.

Comment: @davips Are you sure that the `f` parameter to `funcToRunnable` is lazy?

Comment: Intellij was complaining about `f: => ()` so I put `f: => Unit`. Should be there any difference?

Answer (score 5):

With Actors without tying up a thread:

```scala
import actors.{TIMEOUT, Actor}
import actors.Actor._

private case class Ping( client: Actor, update: Int )
private case class Pulse()
case class Subscribe( actor: Actor )
case class Unsubscribe( actor: Actor )

class PulseActor extends Actor {
  def act = eventloop {
        case ping: Ping => { sleep(ping.update); ping.client ! Pulse }
  }
  def sleep(millis: Long) =
    receiveWithin(millis) {
      case TIMEOUT =>
  }
}

class ServiceActor extends Actor {

  var observers: Set[Actor] = Set.empty
  val pulseactor = new PulseActor
  val update = 2000

  def act = {
    pulseactor.start
    pulseactor ! new Ping( this, update )
    loop {
      react {
        case sub: Subscribe => observers += sub.actor
        case unsub: Unsubscribe => observers -= unsub.actor
        case Pulse => pulse
      }
    }
  }


  def pulse {  
    //cpuload = CPUprofile.getCPUload.getOrElse{ List(0.0) }  //real work
    observers foreach { observer => observer ! "CPUloadReport( cpuload )" }
    pulseactor ! Ping(this, update)
  }
}

object Exercise extends App {
  val deamon = new ServiceActor
  deamon.start
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Scala 2.11.x, Akka actors seems to be the best way to do this IMHO. First create a task scheduling library:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.concurrent.duration._
val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
val scheduler = actorSystem.scheduler
implicit val executor = actorSystem.dispatcher

// do once after period millis
def doOnce(fn: => Unit, period:Long) = scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds)(fn) 
// do regularly every period millis starting now
def doRegularly(fn: => Unit, period:Long) = scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, period milliseconds)(fn)
// do regularly every period millis if whileFn is true, starting now 
def doWhile(fn: => Unit, whileFn: => Boolean, period:Long) {
 if (whileFn) {
    fn
    doOnce(doWhile(fn, whileFn, period), period)
 }
}
```

Then use this as:

```
doRegularly({
  println("hello world!")
}, 1000) // repeat every 1000 millisecs

doWhile({
  println("Sleeping!")
}, whileDaylight, 1000) // repeat every 1000 millisecs whileDaylight is true
```