# Play 2.4: Schedule a recurring task at app startup with dependency injection

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I need to schedule a recurring task on the application start, the task itself is very simple just send to the application a fire-and-forget HTTP call. I'm not a play expert, buy i would assume that s straightforward solution would be something like using `play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system.schedule` in `Global.onStart`. Since Play 2.4, `Global` configuration is somewhat deprecated in favor of new Guice DI. Hacking the advice from the [DI documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection) i couldn't come up with a nice solution for this issue. The best i managed to get is writing a wrapper on top of `GuiceApplicationLoader` calling a custom implementation of `BuiltInComponentsFromContext`, but in this case i can't use injection to get `WSClient`. What's the best way to rewrite something like this with Play 2.4:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) = {
    Akka.system.schedule(2.hours, 2.hours, theTask)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: this is now better documented for Play 2.6: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScheduledTasks

---

You can solve this by creating a module like this (attention to code comments):

```
package tasks

import javax.inject.{Singleton, Inject}

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle

// Using the default ExecutionContext, but you can configure
// your own as described here:
// https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ThreadPools
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MyRecurrentTaskModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    // binding the RecurrentTask as a eager singleton will force
    // its initialization even if RecurrentTask is not injected in
    // any other object. In other words, it will starts with when
    // your application starts.
    bind(classOf[RecurrentTask]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}

@Singleton
class RecurrentTask @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem, lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {

  // Just scheduling your task using the injected ActorSystem
  actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(1.second, 1.second) {
    println("I'm running...")
  }

  // This is necessary to avoid thread leaks, specially if you are
  // using a custom ExecutionContext
  lifecycle.addStopHook{ () =>
    Future.successful(actorSystem.shutdown())
  }

}
```

After that, you must enable this module adding the following line in your `conf/application.conf` file:

```
play.modules.enabled += "tasks.MyRecurrentTaskModule"
```

Then, just start you application, fire a request to it and see the scheduled task will run every each second.

**References**:

1. [Understanding Play thread pools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ThreadPools)
2. [Play Runtime Dependency Injection for Scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection)
3. [Integrating with Akka](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka)

**Related questions**:

1. [How to correctly schedule task in Play Framework 2.4.2 scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679563/how-to-correctly-schedule-task-in-play-framework-2-4-2-scala)
2. [Was asynchronous jobs removed from the Play framework? What is a better alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007478/was-asynchronous-jobs-removed-from-the-play-framework-what-is-a-better-alternat)

Comment: I guess this is the most reasonable solution, though still feels like a hack to me. Hope they will make a more sensible way to work with app lifecycle hooks.

Comment: It don't feels like a hack to me, but I would agree that it is more verbose than expected, at least for a single task.