# creating a scheduled task in scala with play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to create a scheduled task in Play 2.5. I found some resources related to this topic but none of them were for Play 2.5. I found out [this resource](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaAkka#Scheduling-asynchronous-tasks) related to what I am looking for and it looks good. Also on the same link there is a migration guide from 2.4 to 2.5.

The examples from older versions used `GlobalSettings` as base but this was deprecated in 2.5. The migration guide is important because it says that we should use dependency injection instead of extending this trait. I am not sure how to do that.

Can you give me some guidance?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34803018/4600. It is basically the same thing for Play 2.5.

Answer (score 9):

You need to run sheduled task inside Akka Actor:

**SchedulerActor.scala**

```
package scheduler

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import akka.actor.Actor
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import play.api.Logger

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

@Singleton
class SchedulerActor @Inject()()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ =>
      // your job here
  }
}
```

**Scheduler.scala**

```
package scheduler

import javax.inject.{Inject, Named}

import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import play.api.{Configuration, Logger}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class Scheduler @Inject() (val system: ActorSystem, @Named("scheduler-actor") val schedulerActor: ActorRef, configuration: Configuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
  val frequency = configuration.getInt("frequency").get
  var actor = system.scheduler.schedule(
    0.microseconds, frequency.seconds, schedulerActor, "update")

}
```

**JobModule.scala**

```
package modules

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport
import scheduler.{Scheduler, SchedulerActor}

class JobModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure() = {
    bindActor[SchedulerActor]("scheduler-actor")
    bind(classOf[Scheduler]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

**application.conf**

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.JobModule"
```

Comment: For me this works only locally unfortunately. When I package the app with `sbt stage` and deploy to a server, it won't start up: `Oops, cannot start the server. Cannot load module` [...] `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: modules.JobModule`. Am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I tested it only with packages builded with sbt native packager and it works like a charm. I will try look into your problem during weekend.

Comment: Your solution works indeed in production too. It seems there was something wrong with Azure's automated deployment (I hate it). Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use akka, you can use java:

- ScheduledFuture
- ScheduledExecutorService

**DemoDaemon.scala:**

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, ScheduledFuture, TimeUnit}
import javax.inject._
import play.Configuration
import scala.util.Try

class DemoDaemon @Inject() (conf: Configuration) {

  val isEnabled = conf.getBoolean("daemon.enabled")
  val delay = conf.getLong("daemon.delay")

  private var scheduledTaskOption : Option[ScheduledFuture[_]] = None

  def task(): Unit = {

    Try {
      println("doSomething")
    } recover {
      case e: Throwable => println(e.getMessage)
    }
  }

  def start(): Unit = {
    if (isEnabled) {
      val executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)

      scheduledTaskOption = Some( 
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
          new Runnable {
            override def run() = task()
          },
          delay, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS
        )
      )
    } else {
      println("not enabled")
    }
  }

  def stop(): Unit = {
    scheduledTaskOption match {
      case Some(scheduledTask) =>
        println("Canceling task")
        val mayInterruptIfRunning = false
        scheduledTask.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
      case None => println("Stopped but was never started")
    }
  }
}
```

**DaemonService.scala**

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
import scala.concurrent.Future

class DaemonService @Inject() (appLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle, daemon: DemoDaemon) {

  daemon.start()

  appLifecycle.addStopHook{ () =>
    Future.successful(daemon.stop())
  }
}
```

**JobModule.scala**

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class JobModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[DaemonService]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

**application.conf**

```
daemon.enabled = true
daemon.delay = 10
play.modules.enabled += "com.demo.daemon.JobModule"
```